# Intel XDK build error for android

Tags: android, cordova, build, intel-xdk

When building the app, which has been working, I am now getting an error on build. I can't tell where to even start looking based on the log.  Here is the end of the log containing the error.

```
-dex:
  [dex] input: .../ccbklynmobileapp/platforms/android/ant-build/classes
  [dex] input: .../ccbklynmobileapp/platforms/android/CordovaLib/ant-build/classes.jar
  [dex] input: .../ccbklynmobileapp/platforms/android/libs/gcm.jar
  [dex] input: .../ccbklynmobileapp/platforms/android/libs/android-support-v13.jar
  [dex] input: .../ccbklynmobileapp/platforms/android/libs/Pushwoosh.jar
  [dex] Pre-Dexing .../ccbklynmobileapp/platforms/android/CordovaLib/ant-build/classes.jar -> classes-8103adfe520dedd7c805c9ac1183d778.jar
  [dex] Pre-Dexing .../ccbklynmobileapp/platforms/android/libs/gcm.jar -> gcm-f8832f1bdb374e252e21f7ad4fae1e5f.jar
  [dex] Pre-Dexing .../ccbklynmobileapp/platforms/android/libs/android-support-v13.jar -> android-support-v13-263dd5f745d4b285b7a38602ae8381a5.jar
  [dex] Pre-Dexing .../ccbklynmobileapp/platforms/android/libs/Pushwoosh.jar -> Pushwoosh-fd5bbdbd4b5a09374d29557aca058a88.jar
  [dex] Converting compiled files and external libraries into .../ccbklynmobileapp/platforms/android/ant-build/classes.dex...
   [dx] Merged dex A (120 defs/154.9KiB) with dex B (207 defs/313.8KiB). Result is 327 defs/569.8KiB. Took 0.6s
   [dx] Merged dex A (327 defs/569.8KiB) with dex B (4 defs/18.7KiB). Result is 331 defs/746.5KiB. Took 0.2s
   [dx] Merged dex A (331 defs/746.5KiB) with dex B (535 defs/572.2KiB). Result is 866 defs/1731.6KiB. Took 0.3s
   [dx] 
   [dx] UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
   [dx] com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lcom/google/android/gcm/GCMBaseIntentService;
   [dx]     at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.readSortableTypes(DexMerger.java:593)
   [dx]     at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.getSortedTypes(DexMerger.java:551)
   [dx]     at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeClassDefs(DexMerger.java:532)
   [dx]     at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:169)
   [dx]     at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:187)
   [dx]     at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.mergeLibraryDexBuffers(Main.java:439)
   [dx]     at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:287)
   [dx]     at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:230)
   [dx]     at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:199)
   [dx]     at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:103)
   [dx]
```

BUILD FAILED
/Developer/android-sdk-linux/tools/ant/build.xml:892: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/Developer/android-sdk-linux/tools/ant/build.xml:894: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/Developer/android-sdk-linux/tools/ant/build.xml:906: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/Developer/android-sdk-linux/tools/ant/build.xml:284: null returned: 2

Total time: 33 seconds
Error code 1 for command: ant with args: release,-f,.../ccbklynmobileapp/platforms/android/build.xml,-Dout.dir=ant-build,-Dgen.absolute.dir=ant-gen
Command finished with error code 2: .../ccbklynmobileapp/platforms/android/cordova/build --release
Error: .../ccbklynmobileapp/platforms/android/cordova/build: Command failed with exit code 2
    at ChildProcess.whenDone (/Developer/cordova/3.5.0-0.2.7/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/cordova/superspawn.js:135:23)
    at ChildProcess.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
    at maybeClose (child_process.js:743:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:810:5)

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem. I was loading another push notification plugin that I was testing before I started using pushwoosh. I removed the call to the other plugin and it works.